# Facebook Credit Implementation is not working

Tags: facebook-credits

I am developer and trying to implement FB credits in my app "mindmatcher". I created an app with name "mindmatcher" and then created two scripts as per the sample given here:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/489/

You can access the page I created by clicking here:

http://apps.facebook.com/mindmatcher/testBeforeCallback.php

I have set the Call Back URL in the app settings.

This callback.php is also created as per the sample given on the above URL. But when I click on Pay Now FB button, it always shows error which can be seen by clicking on this URL:

"**There Was a Problem Processing Your Payment**

**Sorry, but we're having trouble processing your payment. You have not been charged for this transaction. Please try again.**"

Need help to fix this issue asap because I need to make the app live very soon.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the function given below.

```
 function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

  // decode the data
  $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

  if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
    error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
    return null;
  }

  // check sig
  $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
  if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
    error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
    return null;
  }

  return $data;
}


function base64_url_decode($input) {
  return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}
```

Make sure that you call this function properly.